What causes the failure to navigate between items presented by the same component in Angular 16?
I have been working on an SPA with Angular 16, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).
I run into a strange problem while working on a movies search feature.
In app\services\movie-service.service.ts I have:
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MovieResponse, Movie } from '../models/Movie';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MovieService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public searchMovies(searchTerm: string): Observable<MovieResponse> {
    return this.http.get<MovieResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/search/movie?api_key=${environment.apiKey}&query=${searchTerm}`);
  }
}

I use the method above inside the TopBarComponent like this:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieResponse, Movie } from '../../models/Movie';
import { MovieService } from '../../services/movie-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.scss']
})
export class TopBarComponent {
  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  public searchTerm: string = '';
  public isSearch: boolean = false;
  public timeOutInterval: number = 500;
  public searchResultsResponse!: MovieResponse;
  public searchResults: Movie[] | undefined = [];

  public hideSearchResults(): void {
    this.isSearch = false;
  }

  public debounceMovieSearch(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.doMovieSearch(), this.timeOutInterval);
  }
  
  public doMovieSearch() {
    if (this.searchTerm && this.searchTerm.length > 2) {
      this.isSearch = true;
      this.movieService.searchMovies(this.searchTerm).subscribe((response) => {
        this.searchResultsResponse = response;
        this.searchResults = this.searchResultsResponse.results;
      })
    } else {
      this.isSearch = false;
    }
  }
}

Search form:
<form class="search_form w-100 mx-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="search" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (input)="debounceMovieSearch()" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" class="form-control search-box">
      <button class="btn btn-search" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="isSearch" (clickOutside)="hideSearchResults()" class="search-results shadow-sm">
      <div *ngIf="searchResults && searchResults.length">
        <a routerLink="/movie/{{ movie.id }}" *ngFor="let movie of searchResults">
          <app-search-item [movie]="movie"></app-search-item>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="!(searchResults && searchResults.length)">
        <p class="m-0 p-2 text-center">No movies found for this search</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  
  

The routes in the app\app-routing.module.ts:
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent, data: { title: 'Now playing' } },
  { path: 'top-rated', component: TopMoviesComponent, data: { title: 'Top Rated' } },
  { path: 'movie/:id', component: MovieDetailsComponent, data: { title: '' } },
  { path: 'actor/:id', component: ActorDetailsComponent, data: { title: '' } },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, data: { title: '' } },
];
  

The result looks like this:

The problem
Clicking a movie item in the searcg results list will navigate us to the movie details route (MovieDetailsComponent), except when we already are on a movie details page.
Stackblitz
There is a Stackblitz with all the code I have so far.
Questions

What am I doing wrong?
What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?


You are almost correct, what you are missing is using paramMap rather than snapshot in the movie-details.component, so you can react to the movie id changes.
You need to address this change on the function getMovieDetails like so:
getMovieDetails(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => params.get('id')), // retrieve id from route
    switchMap((id: string | undefined | null) => {
      if (id) return this.movieService.getMovieDetails(Number(id));
      return of(undefined); // if there is no id, then return undefined
   })
  ).subscribe((response: Movie | undefined) => {
     if (response) { // if movie exists then do something...
        this.movie = response;
        // ...
     }
  })
}

Additionally, since paramMap returns an observable, keep in mind that you should only subscribe in one place, that is why I am using pipe and returning the final observable result, which is either a Movie or undefined

I get this error: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<ParamMap, string | null>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<ParamMap, string | undefined>'.

Please try answering this question too. Thanks!

When you navigate from movie/1 to movie/2, MovieDetailsComponent isn't recreated. Because you don't listen for id changes, the component doesn't know that movie id has changed and it needs to update the view. So listen to route parameter changes:
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
    const movie_id = Number(paramMap.get('id'));
    this.getMovieDetails(movie_id);
  });
}


You are subscribing twice, one time from paramMap and the other from movieService, in other words, you are suggesting doing a subscribe(() => observable.subscribe()) which is callback hell, a bad practice. You need to pipe it and subscribe in one place

I agree with you. Actually, this would be the third subscription, as there are already two, so I was just following OP's style.
